# Website jumps to top when scrolling down

Tags: pages

I have a problem with one of my customers pages. When I click a link on the website or when I refresh the page, it automatically jumps back to the top when I immediately start scrolling. If I wait for some seconds it won't do that. Any suggestions on how to solve that problem?

This is the website I'm describing:

https://www.ingenieur-group.de/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you start to scroll before the page finish loading, it will jump back to the top.

You can add a Preloader to hide the content of the page until it is fully loaded to prevent this (https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/preloader/).

Comment: The jumping isn't normal behaviour I don't think. This might work, yes, but it'd be better to work out why it's jumping and stop that rather than work around the bug.